# Cocoa - dual full screen mode?

Tags: cocoa, fullscreen

I'm an ObjC / Cocoa novice.

I have a `WebView` which I wish to display full screen across two screens side-by-side.

Using `NSView enterFullScreenMode` with the `NSFullScreenModeAllScreens` option I can make my app go full screen, but the `WebView` only fills my left-hand primary display - the secondary (right hand) display stays black.

Is it possible to make the `WebView` fill both screens?

Comment: A hackintoshy solution, but how about rendering the webview in 2 parts, so you can display them in 2 views

Comment: it's one big web app - needs to be one webview

Comment: what's the approach of handling different resolution screens of your webapp?

Comment: @Eimantas it doesn't have to - we can require both screens to be the same resolution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer myself:

```
NSDictionary *opts = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSFullScreenModeAllScreens,
       nil];

NSView *view = [window contentView];
[view enterFullScreenMode:[NSScreen mainScreen] withOptions:opts];

NSRect frame = [view.window frame];
frame.size.width *= 2;
[view.window setContentSize:frame.size];
```

The last line is the important one - it's necessary to set the size of `view.window` rather than the `window` property of the application delegate.  For reasons I don't yet understand those don't appear to be the same thing.

Comment: In Mavericks you also need to deselect the "Displays Have Separate Spaces" option in the Mission Control settings in System Preferences.